# Include Maven dependencies in the assembly war?

Tags: maven-2

I am creating an assembly with `packaging=war`.
I need to include few of the jars, which have been declared as project dependencies in pom.xml in my war (`web-inf/lib`)

How can I do this?

Edited on 15/10-
 My project creates few assemblies, one of which is supposed to give packaging of type-war.
Some jar files, which are dependencies for the project(and have been declared in pom.xml)need be included in war under WEB-INF.
How can I include them or how can i point out their paths to my local nexus repository path?

Comment: You create your war file using the "classic" packaging plugin from Maven or do you create it using the assembly plugin ? In the latter case, you have an assembly.xml file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you be more precise? By default, when you run the `mvn clean install` command on a `war` project, Maven 2 will include all dependencies in `WEB-INF/lib` directories, excluding the ones with the scope `test` and `provided`.

---

If you create your war file using an [assembly](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/), then you have an `assembly.xml` file, which defines the content of your final war file. In this file, you can specify the list of dependencies you want to include:

```
<assembly>
    ...
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
           <includes>
               <include>log4j:log4j</include>
               <include>commons-lang:commons-lang</include>
               ...
           </includes>
           <unpack>false</unpack>
           <outputDirectory>WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

(in this example, I asked to add `log4j` and `commons-lang` dependencies).
For each dependency, you need to specify the groupId and the artifactId. The version is automatically detected regarding the list of dependencies you have set in your `pom.xml` file.

Comment: @romaintaz, the scopes included in the war are runtime and compile. test and provided are not included

Comment: Yes, I made a little mistake. As the scope "compile" is the default scope, it's better if Maven2 include them directly in the war indeed ;)

Comment: I have edited my answer in order to consider the case where you are indeed using the assembly plugin to build your war file.